# Select elements from two different dropdown menus using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a dynamic table. To do this, I need to select elements from two different dropdown menus iteratively. First, I want to select the first element of dropdown_secciones, then I want to select the fist element of dropdown_circuitos and finally click the show button (mostrar_click.click()). This would be the first iteration. The second iteration should select the second element of dropdown_circuitos and then click the show button again. No new elements from the first dropdown (dropdown_secciones) should be selected until all elements are selected from dropdown_circuitos.

This is the code I have so far which isn´t working properly:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')
main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)

driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")

dropdown_secciones = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select')
select_box_secciones = Select(dropdown_secciones)
options_secciones = select_box_secciones.options

dropdown_circuitos = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbCircuitos"]')
select_box_circuitos = Select(dropdown_circuitos)
options_circuitos = select_box_circuitos.options

mostrar_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/input[1]')

for index in range(0, len(options_secciones) - 1):
    select_box_secciones.select_by_index(index)
    mostrar_click.click()

    for i in range(0, len(options_circuitos) - 1):

        select_box_circuitos.select_by_index(i)
        circuitos.append(select_box_circuitos.get_attribute('innerHtml'))
        mostrar_click.click()
```

I am quite new with selenium but I guess I should some how break the first iteration when an element is found and then "jump" to the second interation. Anyway, any ideas on how to improve the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've come up with something that should help. Here are some notes:

- The second dropdown behaviour changes as you work with the first, so I've moved that stuff in the loop itself
- Some frame switches are needed so I've just added some functions to make it easier (switch_to_top and switch_to_main)
- The index in the for loops should start at 1 as 0 will select the default value
- When the table loads, I've just added a wait to cater for this
- I've used find by id in some places where you've used xpath as I believe it's better practice

One line I wasn't sure about was `circuitos.append(select_box_circuitos.get_attribute('innerHtml'))` so I've left that, I don't know what the intention here is but I don't think that line will work. You can comment this out initially to check the rest works.

Also ensure to add the imports for the wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')

def switch_to_top():
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")

def switch_to_main():
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("mainFrame")

main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)

switch_to_top()

dropdown_secciones = driver.find_element_by_id('cmbSecciones')
select_box_secciones = Select(dropdown_secciones)
options_secciones = select_box_secciones.options

mostrar_click = driver.find_element_by_id('cmdMostrar')

for index in range(1, len(options_secciones)):
    if (index > 1):
        switch_to_top()
    select_box_secciones.select_by_index(index)

    dropdown_circuitos = driver.find_element_by_id('cmbCircuitos')
    select_box_circuitos = Select(dropdown_circuitos)
    items_circuitos = select_box_circuitos.options

    for i in range(1, len(items_circuitos)):
        if (i > 1):
            switch_to_top()
        select_box_circuitos.select_by_index(i)
        circuitos.append(select_box_circuitos.get_attribute('innerHtml'))
        mostrar_click.click()
        switch_to_main()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body>table")))
```